# PhD interview presentation (invited)

Tags: phd, presentation, interview

I've got invited to a lab seminar. I am so excited and nervous, too.

I applied for the same research group before, and unfortunately, I was not selected after short presentation and interview at a conference.

Instead, the PI (call A) recommends me to the chief of the research center and another PI (call B) saying they have one open position. 
So, B invited me to come to Switzerland (French speaking area) and join the lab meeting.

PI said the entire members attend the meeting usually and I have 30 minutes for a presentation. I guess at least 15 people will be at the seminar.

So now I am considering that the presentation consists of
1) Research during my master: I have three published articles in peer-review journals (first author), one article published in a peer-reviewed journal (co-author) and a couple of studies under revision and ongoing research. I am going to categorize them into two themes and summarize the main objectives and results.
2) Research skills 
3) Research interests related to the project.

It is not just I introduce the research to other people in an international conference. I would like to become a part of them, and there has to be some evaluation as a prospective PhD student and co-worker.

But, I have never been in the position. I would be grateful if anyone gives me some advice on the presentation. I don’t want to lose the opportunity again.

Comment: "Research interests related to the project," what project?

Comment: You have thirty minutes. Perhaps only twenty-five, because you might want to leave five minutes for questions. You cannot present four articles, a couple of studies, and ongoing research. (I'm sceptical of how you managed to publish four articles -- they will probably be too -- you might need to justify.) That's far too much information. If all the articles are closely related, then maybe opt for a high-level overview of those articles and what you want to do during your PhD.

Comment: What is your field? In what journals have you published? With three articles as first author you should be able to choose any lab you want to work...

Comment: The expected presentation lengh is less than 45 min. So I thought 30 min would be good. And my major is MR physics and application in psychiatric diseases. The funded project is for the study of psychiatirc disease using MRI.

Comment: Read the latest articles by that group to see what they are interested in, so that you can relate to this in your talk. You don't want to just talk about yourself, you also want to explain why you fit *there* rather than somewhere else.

Comment: Have you asked the PI what they expect? Is this an interview seminar or a research seminar? Clear communication is never a bad thing, especially when starting a new relationship.